# Forwarding both TCP and UDP to a google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have this Google instance where another Ephemeral IP is forwarded to. In fact all TCP ports on that IP is getting forwarded to the target instance.

Now what I need to do is to forward all UDP ports from the same IP to the same instance. 
Unfortunately running this command:

gcutil --service_version="v1" --project="trainer-484" addforwardingrule "eu-rule-1-1-udp" --region="europe-west1" --protocol="UDP" --target="eu-pool" --ip="x.y.x.x"

I get the following error:
Invalid value for field 'resource.natIP': 'natIP/x.y.x.x'. Resource was not found.

This is a serious problem as we need to be able to forward all protocols not just a subset of protocols.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add another forwarding rule to that ephemeral IP (See documentation at [1]).

You need to reserve an IP with command :
gcutil --project="trainer-484" reserveaddress --region="europe-west1" ip-name

Than you can use the reserved IP to add forwarding rules.

Kind Regards,
Paolo

[1] - https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/reference/forwardingrule

Comment: Unfortunately there is a limit of 7 static IPs per region and it seems there is no clear path to ask to increase this limit. (The quota increase form does not have any option for this)